# Using gdist() function

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial

I want to find the distance between one fixed coordinate (lat,long) and many other coordinate from that fixed coordinate. For  ex: I have a locality x and in that locality their are around 1100 merchants. I have the geo location of the of the locality and the geo location of the merchants as well. Now, i want to find the between x and each of the merchant.
I am using the `gdist()` fucntion for calculating the distance. But the code calculates it between two points and i want to calculate the distance between x and 1100 merchants at one go. How can i do that??
The code is given below:

```
gdist(lon.1, lat.1, lon.2, lat.2, units = "nm", a = 6378137.0, b = 6356752.3142, verbose = FALSE)
```

Comment: I ran the code given below. The code ran perfectly but there was no output:                                                                                                 distance <-as.data.frame(gdist(geo$pickup_longitude,geo$pickup_latitude,77.6249622,12.9404097,units = "km", a = 6378137.0, b = 6356752.3142, verbose = FALSE))

Comment: what's `gdist`? Please edit your post and make it a reproducible example including the necessary packages and data to reproduce the problem.

Comment: gdist() is a function which is a part of the Imap package in R.                gdist() gives the geodesic distance between two points specified by latitude/longitude using Vincenty
inverse formula for ellipsoids. The distance is given in nautical miles (the default), meters,
kilometers, or miles. gdist.total() applies gdist() to any number of line segments.

Comment: Well, if the function returns the distance between two points, you would have to write a loop that iterates over the 1100 merchants

Answer (score 0):

To get the distances from `c(-73.001, 40.21)` to `df[, c("lon", "lat")]` in meters, you could use

```
df <- data.frame("name" = LETTERS[1:4], 
                 "lon" = c(23.231, 1.23, 115.40, -87.98), 
                 "lat" = c(32.78, -34.30, 21.92, -12.2))
library(geosphere)
mat <- distm(c(-73.001, 40.21), as.matrix(df[, -1]))
colnames(mat) <- df$name
mat
#            A        B        C       D
# [1,] 8209788 11253350 13066503 6035987
```

Comment: @ luke i didn't understand the code. Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand?